# How to limit a criteria to fk's in another table?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a table, `car`, each car has an `id` that may appear in `option` (options are stuff like defrosters, power windows, etc) in the column `FK_car_id`. So `car` has a 0-to-many relationship with `option`.

I need ***cars with options***.

The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT c.* from car c
  LEFT JOIN options o on c.id = o.FK_car_id
  GROUP BY c.id;
```

How do I do this in hibernate? Here's what I've tried:

```
var c = newCriteria().readOnly();

c.createAlias('car','car');
c.sqlRestriction('SELECT c.* from car c LEFT JOIN options o on c.id = o.FK_car_id GROUP BY c.id');

c.return c.list(asQuery = false);
```

But I get "Could not extract Result Set".

---

*Note: this is a simplified representation of my code to highlight the main issue and produce a minimal example.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
c.createCriteria(Car.class, "car")
      .createAlias("car.options", "options", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
      .setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("car.id"));
```